# How to make a server side data request via react.js

Tags: python, reactjs

My App component in React.js currently accesses hard-coded data stored in a js variable. I want to instead fetch this piece of data by making a GET or POST request to the python flask server running for the application.

```
React.renderComponent( <App data={dataset}/>, document.getElementById( "App" ) );
```

Let's say the data can be accessed by the url /get_dataset.json on python flask.
How do alter the code here?

Comment: There is nothing specific that React adds for this use case. So you could use whatever tools you like (e.g. jQuery) to make an ajax request, retrieve the data from your endpoint and then call `React.renderComponent()` w/ the data you have now available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using jQuery for ajax, you could wait to render the component until after you get the response:

```
$.get('/get_dataset.json', function(dataset) {
  React.renderComponent( <App data={dataset}/>, document.getElementById( "App" ) );
});
```

or you could do it inside the component as seen [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html)

Comment: Logically, this should work. But the React.renderComponent isn't been called from with the $.get() ajax call. 
I tried passing my good old static data to React.renderComponent from within the $.get() call. Even that did not work.